# LinkedIn Ads API - Cannot change targeting due to locale

Tags: linkedin-api, ads

Here is the targeting that I want to change for a specific LinkedIn Ads campaign:

```
{
  "patch": {
    "$set": {
      "targetingCriteria": {
        "exclude": {
          "or": {
            "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:titles": ["urn:li:title:19"],
            "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:industries": ["urn:li:industry:17", "urn:li:industry:59"]
          }
        },
        "include": {
          "and": [
            {
              "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:groups": ["urn:li:group:136630", "urn:li:group:153107", "urn:li:group:161195", "urn:li:group:2086261", "urn:li:group:2215380", "urn:li:group:27040", "urn:li:group:2796718", "urn:li:group:3983510", "urn:li:group:3988629", "urn:li:group:4004399", "urn:li:group:4021192", "urn:li:group:4086037", "urn:li:group:4089740", "urn:li:group:4089895", "urn:li:group:4091212", "urn:li:group:4091259", "urn:li:group:4092037", "urn:li:group:4093000", "urn:li:group:4094813", "urn:li:group:4094977", "urn:li:group:4372672", "urn:li:group:4520041", "urn:li:group:4584249", "urn:li:group:4975895", "urn:li:group:65094", "urn:li:group:6793801", "urn:li:group:136630", "urn:li:group:153107", "urn:li:group:161195", "urn:li:group:2086261", "urn:li:group:2215380", "urn:li:group:27040", "urn:li:group:2796718", "urn:li:group:3983510", "urn:li:group:3988629", "urn:li:group:4004399", "urn:li:group:4021192", "urn:li:group:4086037", "urn:li:group:4089740", "urn:li:group:4089895", "urn:li:group:4091212", "urn:li:group:4091259", "urn:li:group:4092037", "urn:li:group:4093000", "urn:li:group:4094813", "urn:li:group:4094977", "urn:li:group:4372672", "urn:li:group:4520041", "urn:li:group:4584249", "urn:li:group:4975895", "urn:li:group:65094", "urn:li:group:6793801"],
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:jobFunctions": ["urn:li:function:4", "urn:li:function:21", "urn:li:function:8", "urn:li:function:9", "urn:li:function:18", "urn:li:function:20", "urn:li:function:25", "urn:li:function:26"]
              }
            },
            {
              "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:profileLocations": ["urn:li:geo:106693272"]
              }
            },
            {
              "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:interfaceLocales": ["urn:li:locale:de_DE"]
              }
            },
            {
              "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:staffCountRanges": ["urn:li:staffCountRange:(2,10)", "urn:li:staffCountRange:(11,50)", "urn:li:staffCountRange:(51,200)", "urn:li:staffCountRange:(201,500)"]
              }
            },
            {
              "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:industries": ["urn:li:industry:112", "urn:li:industry:114", "urn:li:industry:117", "urn:li:industry:135", "urn:li:industry:142", "urn:li:industry:143", "urn:li:industry:144", "urn:li:industry:145", "urn:li:industry:146", "urn:li:industry:147", "urn:li:industry:18", "urn:li:industry:19", "urn:li:industry:20", "urn:li:industry:21", "urn:li:industry:25", "urn:li:industry:26", "urn:li:industry:34", "urn:li:industry:48", "urn:li:industry:49", "urn:li:industry:52", "urn:li:industry:53", "urn:li:industry:54", "urn:li:industry:55", "urn:li:industry:56", "urn:li:industry:57", "urn:li:industry:58", "urn:li:industry:60", "urn:li:industry:61", "urn:li:industry:62", "urn:li:industry:94"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get this error message:

> {"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","message":"Value
> urn:li:locale:**de_DE of urn:li:adTargetingFacet:interfaceLocales
> expected to match value {country=US, language=en}** of
> /locale.","errorDetails":{"inputErrors":[{"description":"Value
> urn:li:locale:de_DE of urn:li:adTargetingFacet:interfaceLocales
> expected to match value {country=US, language=en} of
> /locale","input":{"inputPath":{"fieldPath":"/targetingCriteria"}},"code":"MISMATCH_FIELDS"}]},"status":400}

I really want to target only people that speak German.

If I change the value of urn:li:adTargetingFacet:interfaceLocales to "en_US", it suddenly works, but I really only want to target German speaking users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, thanks for your help Matteo!

In fact, I have created a mock up campaign that I use for testing. I usually implement the changed targeting in this campaign, verify if everything works and then apply the new targeting to the actual campaign.

However, the locale in the mock up campaign is us_EN, and you cannot change that, not even in the LinkedIn UI. So, when I try to implement a new targeting with the locale de_DE, it doesn't work, since that's a feature that you cannot update in the campaign targeting.

I hope this helps others facing similar issues!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: At The moment seems not possibile to update these information for campaign in status Active. Also natively:

[image: error native interface]

Try patching the locale also at the campaign level ([See the campaign schema in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns#schema)), as example:

```
{
    "patch": {
        "$set": {
            "locale": {
                "country": "DE",
                "language": "de"
            },
            "targetingCriteria": {
                "exclude": {
                    "or": {
                        "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:titles": ["urn:li:title:19"],
                        "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:industries": ["urn:li:industry:17", "urn:li:industry:59"]
                    }
                },
                "include": {
                    "and": [{
                            "or": {
                                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:groups": ["urn:li:group:136630", "urn:li:group:153107", "urn:li:group:161195", "urn:li:group:2086261", "urn:li:group:2215380", "urn:li:group:27040", "urn:li:group:2796718", "urn:li:group:3983510", "urn:li:group:3988629", "urn:li:group:4004399", "urn:li:group:4021192", "urn:li:group:4086037", "urn:li:group:4089740", "urn:li:group:4089895", "urn:li:group:4091212", "urn:li:group:4091259", "urn:li:group:4092037", "urn:li:group:4093000", "urn:li:group:4094813", "urn:li:group:4094977", "urn:li:group:4372672", "urn:li:group:4520041", "urn:li:group:4584249", "urn:li:group:4975895", "urn:li:group:65094", "urn:li:group:6793801", "urn:li:group:136630", "urn:li:group:153107", "urn:li:group:161195", "urn:li:group:2086261", "urn:li:group:2215380", "urn:li:group:27040", "urn:li:group:2796718", "urn:li:group:3983510", "urn:li:group:3988629", "urn:li:group:4004399", "urn:li:group:4021192", "urn:li:group:4086037", "urn:li:group:4089740", "urn:li:group:4089895", "urn:li:group:4091212", "urn:li:group:4091259", "urn:li:group:4092037", "urn:li:group:4093000", "urn:li:group:4094813", "urn:li:group:4094977", "urn:li:group:4372672", "urn:li:group:4520041", "urn:li:group:4584249", "urn:li:group:4975895", "urn:li:group:65094", "urn:li:group:6793801"],
                                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:jobFunctions": ["urn:li:function:4", "urn:li:function:21", "urn:li:function:8", "urn:li:function:9", "urn:li:function:18", "urn:li:function:20", "urn:li:function:25", "urn:li:function:26"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "or": {
                                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:profileLocations": ["urn:li:geo:106693272"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "or": {
                                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:interfaceLocales": ["urn:li:locale:de_DE"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "or": {
                                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:staffCountRanges": ["urn:li:staffCountRange:(2,10)", "urn:li:staffCountRange:(11,50)", "urn:li:staffCountRange:(51,200)", "urn:li:staffCountRange:(201,500)"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "or": {
                                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:industries": ["urn:li:industry:112", "urn:li:industry:114", "urn:li:industry:117", "urn:li:industry:135", "urn:li:industry:142", "urn:li:industry:143", "urn:li:industry:144", "urn:li:industry:145", "urn:li:industry:146", "urn:li:industry:147", "urn:li:industry:18", "urn:li:industry:19", "urn:li:industry:20", "urn:li:industry:21", "urn:li:industry:25", "urn:li:industry:26", "urn:li:industry:34", "urn:li:industry:48", "urn:li:industry:49", "urn:li:industry:52", "urn:li:industry:53", "urn:li:industry:54", "urn:li:industry:55", "urn:li:industry:56", "urn:li:industry:57", "urn:li:industry:58", "urn:li:industry:60", "urn:li:industry:61", "urn:li:industry:62", "urn:li:industry:94"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matteo, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I get this error: Campaign/locale cannot be updated unless in draft state. In fact, this is what the documentation for updating campaign says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns#update-a-campaign. In the example, the facet "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:interfaceLocales" is "urn:li:locale:en_US", and in fact it works when I update the campaign with this facet. But when a change it to something different to "urn:li:locale:en_US", it doesn't work.

Comment: can you change the targeting's language natively with the Linkedin UI?

Comment: Hi Matteo, I found the issue, thanks for your help! In fact, I have created a mock up campaign that I use for testing. I usually implement the changed targeting in this campaign, verify if everything works and then apply the new targeting to the actual campaign. However, the locale in the mock up campaign is us_EN, and you cannot change that, not even in the LinkedIn UI, as you implied, and that's why it wasn't working. Anyway, thank you!